# Progress View not updating

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

Im trying to get a progress view working from within a progress block (parse) that returns a % complete.

when i print percent i get :

```
16.0
17.0
18.0
ect
```

so it is returning,  and when i print progressBar.progress i get:

```
0.0
all the way to 
1.0
```

but still the progress bar does not update:

```
}, progressBlock: { (percent) in
   // print(Float(percent))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.progressBar.setProgress(Float(percent/100), animated: true)
            //print(cell.progressBar.progress)
    }

//cell.progessBar.progress = Float(percent)

if percent == 100 {
    cell.progressBar.isHidden = true
}
```

})

note that cell is a custom cell defined thus:

```
func didDoubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let point: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

    if let selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
        // let selectedCell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath as IndexPath)!
        // let indexItem = selectedIndexPath[1]
        // create instance of the cell so we can manipulate the images
        let cell: JourneyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: selectedIndexPath) as! JourneyCollectionViewCell
```

Comment: I'm curious - I don't see a call to self in the Dispatch async block, are you trying to update a progressive from a closure in a reusable cell? If so you may want to couple the progress view at the specific index path outside of a cellForRow method.

Comment: i am not entirely sure.  i just read about the the reference to the dispatch queue in another thread and added it in vain hope.  Can you explain what you mean by 'couple' the progress view view outside of a cell for index method?

Comment: This is actually a custom function where i have applied a double tap gesture to the collectionview, not an override

Comment: Can you add more of the cell's implementation to your question?

Comment: Sure, i updated the question.  below that is just query code, i can add if needed but its a bit long for here.

Comment: This is old now. But I wonder about the “percent/100”. You know that if this is integer divided by integer the result will always be zero until percent == 100/ this would produce the results seen. Instead Float(percent)/100.0 would work.

Answer (score 1):

You were heading in the right direction.  problem with definition of cell.

use the index that was created without the refuse allows editing of cell.

```
let cell: JourneyCollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath ) as! JourneyCollectionViewCell
```